# Hash Ciphers and check with Signature in C

Tags: c, hash, rsa, digital-signature, sha1

I have three binary files: cipher01.bin, cipher02.bin and cipher03.bin.
Additionally I have a sign.bin and a pubkey.pem file. The task is to hash all three ciphers and compare it to the signature. Therefore I used RSA to decrypt the sign.bin with the public key from pubkey.pem.

The result looks good but none of the cipher-hashes belongs to the signature. But I know, that there is at least one cipher which belongs to the signature because it is a task from our university. Maybe I forgot something but I can't figure out what.

Here is my code so far:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <openssl/sha.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <openssl/pem.h>
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
#include <openssl/rsa.h>
#include <openssl/bio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

/** converts unsigned character to readble string*/
char *pt(unsigned char *md) {
  int i;
  char *buf = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*80);

  for(int i = 0; i < SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH;i++) {
    sprintf(&(buf[i*2]),"%02x",md[i]);
  }

  return (buf);
}

/** returns error */
void err_exit(void) {
  printf("%s\n",ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(),NULL));

  ERR_free_strings();
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

/** reads a file */
char * readFile(char * filename,long int * filesize) {
  FILE *fin;
  char *buf;

  if((fin=fopen(filename,"r"))==NULL) {
    printf("Error opening %s.\n",filename);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  fseek(fin,0L,SEEK_END);
  *filesize = ftell(fin);
  rewind(fin);

  if(!(buf=malloc(*filesize))) {
    printf("Memory exhausted. Stop.\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }


  fread(buf,*filesize,1,fin);
  fclose(fin);

  return buf;
}

/** hash a file with sha1 */
char * hashBinaryFile(char * filename) {
  long int filesize = 0;

  EVP_MD_CTX c;
  unsigned char md[SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH];

  ERR_load_crypto_strings();

  EVP_MD_CTX_init(&c);

  /** reads files into buf */
  char * buf = readFile(filename,&filesize);

  if((EVP_DigestInit(&c,EVP_sha1()))==0) {
    err_exit();
  }

  if((EVP_DigestUpdate(&c,buf,filesize))==0) {
    err_exit();
  }

  if((EVP_DigestFinal(&c,md,NULL))==0) {
    err_exit();
  }

  //printf("%s\n",pt(md));

  EVP_MD_CTX_cleanup(&c);
  free(buf);
  ERR_free_strings();

  return pt(md);

}

int padding = RSA_PKCS1_PADDING;

/** loads public key and creates rsa */
RSA * createRSAWithFilename(char * filename,int public) {
  FILE * fp = fopen(filename,"rb");

  if(fp == NULL) {
    printf("Unable to open file %s \n",filename);
    return NULL;    
  }

  RSA *rsa= RSA_new() ;

  if(public) {
    rsa = PEM_read_RSA_PUBKEY(fp, &rsa,NULL, NULL);
  } else {
    rsa = PEM_read_RSAPrivateKey(fp, &rsa,NULL, NULL);
  }

  return rsa;
}

/** decrypt signature */
char * public_decrypt(unsigned char * enc_data,int data_len, unsigned char *decrypted) {
  RSA * rsa = createRSAWithFilename("archieve/pubkey.pem",1);
  int  result = RSA_public_decrypt(data_len,enc_data,decrypted,rsa,padding);
  return pt(decrypted);
}

int main(int argc,char *argv[]) {
  /** decrypt signature */
  long int encrypted_length;
  long int decrypted_length; 
  unsigned char decrypted[4098]={};
  char * encrypted = readFile("archieve/s72897-sig.bin",&encrypted_length);
  char * sign = public_decrypt(encrypted,encrypted_length, decrypted);

  char * cipher01 = hashBinaryFile("archieve/s72897-cipher01.bin");
  char * cipher02 = hashBinaryFile("archieve/s72897-cipher02.bin");
  char * cipher03 = hashBinaryFile("archieve/s72897-cipher03.bin");

  if(strcmp(sign,cipher01)==0) {
    printf("cipher01\n");
  } else if(strcmp(sign,cipher02)==0) {
    printf("cipher02\n");
  } else if(strcmp(sign,cipher03)==0) {
    printf("cipher03\n");
  } else {
    printf("No cipher matches the signature\n");
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Thanks for any kind of help.

Edit: fixed some code

Edit2: link to the *.zip https://ufile.io/tqwoh

Answer (score 2):

You transform your files in human readable format twice:

```
char * public_decrypt(...)
{
    return pt(decrypted);
    //     ^
}

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    char * sign = pt(public_decrypt(encrypted,encrypted_length, decrypted));
    //            ^
```

Additionally, you actually have some memory leaks: You do not free the rsa instance in public_decrypt neither do you free the strings returned (encrypted, sign, cypher0*x*)...

Further recommendation in for pt:

```
char *buf = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 2 * SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH);
```

If you have an appropriate constant already, use it... `sizeof(char)` always is 1 by definition, so you could drop it...

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes , there is one pt too much. But this doesn't solve my problem. Is it helpful for you, if I post all additional files?

Comment: @Draftsman I'm not fully sure about the contents of your files. From your code, I assume the following: The chiper files contain some potentially long, but unencrypted chipers. You need the hash values of their contents. The sign.bin contains the hash value of one of these three  chipers in *binary* form, additionally encrypted with the private key belonging to the public one provided. Is that correct so far? If, however, sign.bin contains the hash in human readable form (but still encrypted), you must not apply pt to it at all...

Comment: You're absolutely right! But after decrypting the public key it has not the same amount of Bytes as the hash values from the cipherXX.bin! I also added my files at the end of the post

Comment: I'll have a look for later - have no running openssl available here and no time to cope with that now...

Comment: I would be very grateful if you can have a look. Thanks for your efforts